# UICollectionview - self.collectionView is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have added UICollectionView from the storyboard and have not used any xib file for the cell. Connected it to my view controller as :

```
@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

This view is a Home page which loads after the user logs in. What is happening is that when the user presses the login button, it goes to the Home Screen and crashes with the error :

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Also : when I print

```
self.myCollectionView in viewDidLoad(), it comes out as nil.
```

**But when I reboot the app with the user now logged in, it works okay and self.myCollectionView is also not nil.**

**Error happens only when going to Home page after user login.**

Here is some part of my code :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    

    var allDevices : [device] = [device]()
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    let retrievedString = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token")
    
    @IBAction func logOutBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        KeychainWrapper.standard.remove(forKey: "token")
        logout()
    }

    let devicesURL = K.devicesURL
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        myCollectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshCollection), for: .valueChanged)
            myCollectionView.dataSource = self
            myCollectionView.delegate = self
            myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    
            AFRequestData()
    
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "deviceCell", for: indexPath) as! MyDeviceCell
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if(cell.deviceName != nil){
                if(cell.deviceImage != nil){
                    cell.deviceName.text = self.allDevices[indexPath.row].givenName
                    cell.deviceImage.image = (self.allDevices[indexPath.row].state == true) ? UIImage(named: "socket-green.png") : UIImage(named: "socket-red.png")
                }
            }

        }

            return cell
        
     }
```

Comment: My guess: You are doing `HomeViewController()` at some point when the user logs in. But since you didn't show the logic code when the user logs in, it's hard to tell... So the relevant codes are: How is shown `HomeViewController` when user is already logged in, and when he's not.

Comment: Thanks you are absolutely right, I solved it just before you commented. I was doing a self.present with HomeViewController(). I changed that to perform segue and the issue went poof. I wasted so many hours on this aaarghhh!!!